# Use "rm" command with inverse match

Tags: bash

I want to remove all files that **do not** match `R1.fastq.gz` in my list of files. 
How do I use `rm` with inverse match?

Comment: This question is off topic on SO. It is not possible with `rm`, you need to use something like `find`  combination with `rm`:  [In linux, how to delete all files EXCEPT the pattern *.txt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78376/in-linux-how-to-delete-all-files-except-the-pattern-txt?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Or `bash` `extglob` feature - also mentioned in the answer you linked to.

Answer (score 15):

Use the extended pattern syntax available in `bash`:

```
shopt -s extglob
printf '%s\n' !(R1.fastq.gz)  # To verify the list of files the pattern matches
rm !(R1.fastq.gz)  # To actually remove them.
```

Or, use `find`:

```
find . ! -name R1.fastq.gz -print         # Verify
find . ! -name R1.fastq.gz -exec rm {} +  # Delete
```

If your version of `find` supports it, you can use `-delete` instead of `-exec rm {} +`:

```
find . ! -name R1.fastq.gz -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ls | grep -v "file_with_string_you_dont_want_to_delete" | xargs rm -f
```

Answer (score -1):

You may want the "invert match" option, `grep –v`, which means "select lines which do not match the regex." and then remove them.

Something like `rm $(ls | grep -v -e "R1.fastq.gz")` should do it.

Please, note that this will erase all files in the folder you are on, **except** `R1.fastq.gz`

Comment: If you want to exclude more than a file, you can append `-e "name"` before the closed parenthesis, E.G. `rm $(ls | grep -v -e "file1" -e "file2" -e "file3")`

Comment: Go to jail, go directly to jail. Do not parse ls, do not collect $200.

Comment: See [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) and [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). If you have a file created with `touch 'hello * world.txt'`, this code will expand the `*` as a glob and delete everything in the directory, **including** the `R1.fastq.gz` files.

Comment: `R1.fastq.gz` could not have possibly been created with a `touch` command, and since the OP have to delete everything except a whitelist of files, the only bad scenario could be if he has some files named `/usr/bin/something`...
It's perfectly legit using `ls` in here, buy those are my two cents, feel free to think it different [:

Comment: Works perfectly :) But there is definitely some philosophical reasons for not doing it :P

Comment: @EsbenEickhardt Yeah, with time I started to avoid parse `ls` myself in whichever way, even if I continue to think what I said 2 years ago: there are cases where it is perfectly safe to use and parse it [: